# Installing APCU for PHP 5.5 on WIndows7

Tags: php, windows-7-x64, php-5.5, apcu

I have ran into a problem attempting to install APCU for PHP5.5
My configuration is:
Windows7 64-bit
PHP 5.5 x86 safe-thread enabled
XAMPP 3.2.1

I tried the following versions of APCU (both thread-safe and non-thread safe and for both 64 and 86):
4.0.10
4.0.8
4.0.7

The php.ini was edited like so:

```
extension=php_apcu.dll
apc.enabled=1
apc.shm_size=32M
apc.ttl=7200
apc.enable_cli=1
apc.serializer=php
```

And phpinfo doesn't show the APCU extension with any of these versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like APCU doesn't like PHP being x86 on the x64 Windows.

I've got it working on the x64 WAMP Server (PHP 5.5) with APCU x64 version. Oddly enough it works only if I add also the old apc.dll - then it sees both APC and APCU. Without the APC it loses APCU (despite complaining that APC is not a valid Win32 application).

Quite random, but might save someone time.